How to avoid Windows Defender false positives with C# software?
I am developing software in C# that includes packet capture functionality.
In Windows, the software must be configured as an exception to the Windows firewall in order to analyze incoming packets.
I have tried two methods to set the software as a firewall exception. And both of these two methods worked well.
The first method is to use INetFwPolicy2 .
INetFwRule2 inboundRule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
inboundRule.Enabled = true;
inboundRule.Profiles = 2 | 4;
inboundRule.Name = "MyApp";
inboundRule.ApplicationName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
// Now add the rule
INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(inboundRule);

Another option is to attach a batch file to the software and have the user run the batch file before first using the software.
@echo off
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="MyApp"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApp" dir=in action=allow program="%~dp0%MyApp.exe" enable=yes

However, both methods may cause Windows Defender to false-posit that the exe or batch file is malware.
When a Windows Defender false positive occurs, we ask Microsoft to modify the definition file.
However, this method requires Microsoft to modify the definition file every time the software is updated.
Also, even if the modification of the Windows Defender definition file prevents Microsoft from detecting false positives once, it may cause false positives to occur again.
Please give me ideas on how to prevent my software from being blocked by Windows Defender.

The firewall rules can anyway only be changed if you run in elevated mode (as administrator), therefore configure these settings during installation, where you normally do have admin rights. Later, admin rights are no more required (and should not be required).

I know that setting up a firewall requires administrator privileges, and that is why my software is implemented to automatically start with administrator privileges.
That said, administrative privileges have nothing to do with my problem this time. My problem is that WindowsDefender recognizes the software as Trojan because the program includes the firewall configuration process.

There must be something else involved. We also have software that does this, and it's never recognized as trojan. I'm therefore quite sure that the firewall setting alone does not trigger the warning. Do you perform some other possibly suspicious actions?

Please see the batch file I wrote. I saved only three lines of processing as setup.bat, but a month ago Windows Defender recognized it as Trojan:Script/Wacatac.B!ml.
(Windows Defender's definition file has been updated and now it does not recognize it as Trojan, but I'm not sure why that happened.)

Check my asnwer

Antiviruses detect if a software is a threat or not, based on heuristic patterns. This means that if the structure of your code is similar to a virus or the program has a behavior similar to a virus (e.g. opening processes) it could be flagged by the antivirus as a virus. In your case the program looks and behaves like a banner grabber. A banner grabber is a port scanner that looks for processes to see what ports are they using and what data is being transferred on those ports. If you want to distribute your application and you do not want it to be flagged as a virus you need either to communicate with antivirus vendors not to flag your application, either to buy a license, either to implement an anti-virus evasion measure, or either to implement a combination of all the above. Other measures that are easily applicable using code are mentioned below:
Application Manifest File
An easy way of doing this is to make the application be launched forcefully as an administrator, but it does not guarantee a 100% success rate. The way this can be done, is to use an 'Application Manifest' file in your application.



In your app manifest replace the field <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" /> with the field         <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />.
The resulting 'Application Manifest' file should be this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
             If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
             requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
            Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
            compatibility.
        -->
         <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on
           and is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements
           and Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
       DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
       to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
       also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. 
       
       Makes the application long-path aware. See https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation -->
  <!--
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
  -->

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!--
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  -->

</assembly>



Exempt the folder where the C# binary is located from Windows Defender actions
Open the terminal as an administrator and enter the command: powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\YOUR_FILE_PATH" (source: Windows Defender - Add exclusion folder programmatically).



Implement both the Application Manifest File and the Windows Defender Exclusion command
namespace WD_Exclusion
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;

    internal class Program
    {
        static void OnStartup()
        {
            // STRINGBUILDER USED TO BUILD THE COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS
            StringBuilder args_builder = new StringBuilder();

            // APPEND THE POWERSHELL WINDOWS DEFENDER EXCLUSION COMMAND
            args_builder.Append("-inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath \"");

            // USE THE APPLICATION'S CURRENT DIRECTORY AS IT'S EXCLUSION TARGET
            args_builder.Append(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            args_builder.Append("\"");



            // INITIATE A "Process" OBJECT
            Process process = new Process();

            // SET THE STARTUP FILE NAME AS THE "PowerShell" EXECUTABLE
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell";

            // SET THE COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS OF THE PROCESS AS THE COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS WITHIN THE "StringBuilder"
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = args_builder.ToString();

            // STRAT THE PROCESS
            process.Start();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ADD THE CURRENT APPLICATION PATH TO THE WINDOWS DEFENDER EXCLUSIONS
            OnStartup();

            // NOTIFY THAT THE EXCLUSION HAD BEEN ADDED
            Console.WriteLine("[ Windows Defender exclusion added ]");
        }
    }
}


Result




I think your approach is useful, but the problem is that Windows Defender deletes the exe file before running that program.
Specifically, when the downloaded zip file is extracted, the exe file inside is deleted, so the user cannot even run the code to prevent the problem.

Create an installer for the file instead of using a zip file by using an Setup Project. This approach is good because you can set an .exe file to run upon the installation. I'll update my answer with an example.

You did not mention anything about signing your application, if not done, that is a one of the ways to prevent false positives (or at least let the vendor take your false positive reports seriously) . You can read more from this answer

Option 1: Submit your app for malware analysis to Microsoft
 Option 2: Buy an "Extended Validation" (EV) code signing certificate
 Option 3: Buy an "Organization Validation" (OV) code signing certificate

