How to correctly format a powershell script in c#?
So writing a C# program which will require network access, thus needing to add a rule to Windows Firewall.
Here is the code:
Console.WriteLine("Firewall not yet configured, doing now.");
PowerShell allowtorthroughwindowsfirewallinbound = PowerShell.Create("New - NetFirewallRule - DisplayName ""Allow TOR through Windows Firewall"" - Direction Inbound - Program ""C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin\\tor.exe"" - Action Allow;')");
allowtorthroughwindowsfirewallinbound.Invoke();

Problem though,the "create" throws the following error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'Create' takes 5 arguments   TorRunner   C:\TorRunner\TorRunner\Program.cs   64  Active

I can only assume the string is formatted incorrectly, so what would be the correct string format for creating a firewall string that would add a windows firewall rule with a name?
Thanks.

Put that string into a Console.WriteLine and keep fixing the escaping of " until it gives you an output which looks as expected. Then that fixed string should work here.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78414068/how-to-avoid-windows-defender-false-positives-with-c-sharp-software, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409790/adding-an-application-firewall-rule-to-both-private-and-public-networks-via-win7/34018032#34018032, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76398401/10024425,

Can you do it without using PowerShell? (A: Yes.)

at the end of string dont need ')

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Management.Automation.RunspaceMode'

This question appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78463277/c-sharp-cant-convert-from-string-to-runspacemode
